# sql use case insensitive match in where in clause

Tags: database, oracle11g, sqlplus

The challenge:

> Display the title of all the books and the isbn from Books database where the CATEGORY is in BUSINESS. The solution shouldn't be dependent on a specific case for the CATEGORY.

I would normally solve it like this, but then the last part confuses me.

```
SELECT title, isbn
FROM books
WHERE category in ('BUSINESS');
```

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `LOWER` function so that the comparison is always done in lower case:

```
SELECT title, isbn
FROM books
WHERE LOWER(category) in ('business');
```

Comment: I've been reading this for quite awhile, and I've missed the meaning of the case part. Thanks you so much.